# gcc compiler not reporting error for inet_ntoa

Tags: c, sockets, networking

How come the compiler doesn't report an error when I use inet_ntoa without the arpa/inet.h include?

I ran this code:

```
struct sockaddr_in dest;
printf("%d\n", inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
```

It returns a signed integer with extremely large magnitude. 
I had the following includes:

```
sys/types.h
sys/socket.h
netinet/in.h
netdb.h
stdio.h
errno.h
sys/time.h
stdlib.h
strings.h
string.h
```

gcc compiler version: 4.1.2 20080704 (red Hat 4.1.2-55)

OS: ssh bash interface to linux system

Comment: You didn't write 3 dots...which headers did you include, and which compiler options did you use on the command line, and which version of the compiler did you use, and probably which o/s are you using it on. Older versions of GCC (pre-5.x) didn't automatically require declarations for functions before they're used (C90 rules); GCC 5.x uses C11 rules by default so functions must be declared before they're used.

Comment: I suppose that remark regarding C90 rules might explain it since i'm using 4.1.2.

Comment: Warnings. Enable them.

Answer (score 0):

The C90 standard does not require functions to be declared or defined before they are used — primarily because to have done so would have broken large quantities of existing C code and one of the primary goals of the standard was to avoid breaking most existing C code.  This means that the C90 compilers infer that the return type of a function that is otherwise undeclared is `int`.  It noted that relying on such implicit declarations was obsolescent.

The C99 standard made good on the promise of obsolescence and requires functions to be declared before they are used; C11 continues that requirement.  However, most compilers continued to allow old style code to compile by default, and GCC was one specific example.  But, in strict C99 compliance mode, such declarations are needed.

Note that functions have to be declared; they do not necessarily have to be given a prototype, though non-prototype declarations are also obsolescent.

Note too that variadic functions — those with an ellipsis `...`in their argument list — must be declared with a prototype before they are used in C90.  That means such well known specimens as `printf()` must be declared with a prototype, which is done trivially by `#include <stdio.h>` (although the standard allows other equivalent mechanisms to be used too).

Older versions of GCC (pre-5.x) didn't automatically require declarations for functions before they're used (C90 rules).  GCC 5.x uses C11 rules by default so functions must be declared before they're used.  All this is by default.  You can control which dialect of C is in use, and which warnings are given.

I typically use GCC with options like:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Werror
```

Some of those options will not be available in GCC 4.1.2, which is fairly old these days (February 2007 judging from the source code available at one of the mirror sites).  For example, it won't support `-std=c11`, but it will support `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99`, and you can use `90` in place of `99`.  The `-Wold-style-definition` option may not work either.  However, the more of these warning options your code can compile with, the better — almost invariably.  The `-Werror` option means the compiler treats warnings as errors; I use it to keep my code clean, but while you're working towards cleanliness, you may choose to leave it off.